# There's a problem with this formula on excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm writing a formula like that

```
=IF(ISBLANK(search_box),0,SEARCH(search_box,$C5&$D5&$E5&$F5))
```

but this isn't work.

When i type this formula on excel i got this problem.

> There's a problem with this formula. No trying to type a formula?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause** The cell is formatted as Text, which causes Excel to ignore any formulas.  This could be directly due to the Text format, or is particularly common when importing data from a CSV or Notepad file.

**Fix** Change the format of the cell(s) to General or some other format.  However, the formulas still won’t start working until you force Excel to reconsider the content.  You can do this in one of two ways.

Answer (score 0):

How about this formulation, no IF() but IFERROR():

[image]

Had to make up some data to play with so you will need to adapt.